# Inverse Laplace transform needed

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method

I need to find the inverse Laplace transform for the following function $$f(s)=\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^{M}\frac{k_i}{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{m_i})}s^{\frac{2}{m_i}}\right)$$ where $k_i>0$, $m_i\geq 2$. Many thanks in advance.